# When and Why should I use long/double instead of Long/Double?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am new in Java/Groovy and I would like to ask when and why I should use long or Long data type.

I am asking this question, because I need to write unit tests for functions where there are types long and Long, and I am trying to understand why they are setting like this.

Comment: Is your question why use long vs some other type (eg int), or when you should use long instead of Long and vice versa?

Comment: @user1675642 "why I should use long or Long data type"

Comment: I know that long is a primitive and Long is an object. My question is in which case I should use it better. Because when I write unit tests for functions I can not test null input for a long.

Comment: Effective Java 2nd Ed Item 49 deals with this question in detail (although other items in the book touch on the question too).

Comment: "Because when I write unit tests for functions I can not test null input for a long" Doesn't this hint as to one reason to choose one over the other: if you choose `long`, you don't need to test passing in `null` because you simply can't. The type system is saving you work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need to use any of the functions or other features of an Object (Long/Double), there is no point using them as they introduce additional overhead - creating objects is more expensive to your system than creating primitives. While this might seem like premature optimization, it is a very easy change to make.

As Andy pointed out you can use them with generics whereas you can't use primitives. I meant this under functions but it is worth pointing out.

Comment: "there is no point using them " Generics?

Comment: That was sort of what I meant by functions, but you're right. Updated the answer.